# How do I break a range into homogeneous sub-ranges in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, range

Say I have a table like this

```
WITH conds(cond) AS (
    SELECT '[3, 5)'::int4range
        UNION
    SELECT '[6, 8)'::int4range
        UNION
    SELECT '[9, 20)'::int4range
)
SELECT cond FROM conds;
```

For a given input range, I want to break it into homogeneous sub-ranges which either are entirely contained in some row in `conds`, or do not overlap with any row in `conds`. There should be an additional column indicating whether each sub-range is covered by `conds`.

More concretely, for an input period of `'[1, 11)'::int4range`, the expected output is

```
  ?column? | ?column?
-----------+----------
 [1,3)     |        f
 [3,5)     |        t
 [5,6)     |        f
 [6,8)     |        t
 [8,9)     |        f
 [9,11)    |        t
(6 rows)
```

Every two rows in `conds` are guaranteed to be disjoint, but `conds` may also be empty (in which case the output is just the input range and `f`), and each `cond` may overlap with the bound of the input range (as shown in the example above).

Which query can achieve this? [This answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97779/postgresql-result-of-range-difference-would-not-be-contiguous) tells me how to handle the case where `cond` only has one row, but it may contain multiple rows for me.

Comment: There are so many special cases: What if conds doesn't overlap the input period, recognizing overlapping conds, conds which overlapt the period bounds, ... I guess, the most effective way is writing a procedural algorithm for that instead of building a messy query with many overlapping checks. I tried with recursive CTEs (cutting the period from the first cond, taking the rest for the second, until no rest is available). This works somehow, but does not fit some edge cases which must be adressed separately. This created a huge unreadable mess of code. Maybe someone can do better...

Comment: @S-Man I have clarified the question and eliminated some edge cases. I think it's safe to use `ORDER BY LOWER(cond)` instead of a recursive CTE now?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a brute force approach -- expand the desired range into individual elements.  Check each of those, and then aggregate back down to ranges:

```
WITH conds(cond) AS (
    SELECT '[3, 5)'::int4range
        UNION ALL
    SELECT '[6, 8)'::int4range
        UNION ALL
    SELECT '[9, 20)'::int4range
)
SELECT int4range(min(r.val), max(r.val) + 1), flag
FROM (SELECT gs.val, (c.cond IS NULL) as flag,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.cond IS NULL ORDER BY gs.val) as seqnum
      FROM (VALUES ('[1, 11)'::int4range)) v(range) CROSS JOIN
           generate_series(lower(v.range), upper(v.range), 1) gs(val) LEFT JOIN
           conds c
           ON gs.val <@ c.cond
     ) r
GROUP BY flag, r.val - seqnum
ORDER BY min(r.val);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4558d293736a621022538fefce27c604) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can also generate the covered and uncovered subranges separately, fusion them together with `UNION`, and give them the correct order with `ORDER BY`

```sql
WITH conds(cond) AS (
    SELECT '[3, 5)'::int4range
    UNION
    SELECT '[6, 8)'::int4range
    UNION
    SELECT '[9, 20)'::int4range
),
     intersections(subrange) AS (
         SELECT cond * '[1, 11)'::int4range
         FROM conds
         WHERE cond && '[1, 11)'::int4range
     ),
     fusion(s, covered) AS (
         SELECT int4range(LAG(UPPER(subrange), 1, LOWER('[1, 11)'::int4range)) OVER (ORDER BY LOWER(subrange)),
                          LOWER(subrange)),
                false
         FROM intersections
         UNION
         SELECT subrange,
                true
         FROM intersections
     )
SELECT s, covered
FROM fusion
ORDER BY LOWER(s)
```